# How to read from device when stdin is pipe

Tags: go, pipe, stdin

So I have a Go program that reads from STDIN as such below. I want the username and password to be entered from keyboard or device but the string slice can be passed using pipe. If I run the command as below:

```sh
echo "Hello World" | go run main.go
```

`os.Stdin` will be set to read from pipes and never the keyboard. Is there a way that I can change `os.Stdin` FileMode as such that it will be reading from device, i.e. keyboard for username and password?

I tried using `os.Stdin.Chmod(FileMode)` but received this error:

> chmod /dev/stdin: invalid argument

```golang
func main() {
  var n = []string{}
  scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
  fmt.Println("Please type anything with Newline Separated, empty line signals termination")
  for scanner.Scan() {
    h := scanner.Text()
    if h == "" {
      break
    }
    n = append(n, h)
  }
  if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Error in reading from STDIN: %v\n", err)
  }

  reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    os.Stdout.WriteString("Username: ")
    username, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Unable to read username: %v\n", err)
  }
  username = strings.TrimSpace(username)

  os.Stdout.WriteString("Password: ")
  bytePassword, _ := terminal.ReadPassword(int(os.Stdin.Fd()))

  password := string(bytePassword)
  os.Stdout.WriteString("\n")
}
```

Comment: To clarify, the goal is to read from stdin and then from the terminal, even if the terminal isn't connected to stdin?

Comment: the goal is to read from stdin which is set to pipe mode in the beginning at the program and starting from this line `reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)`, the mode of stdin is switched to device, i.e. keyboard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can instead read from `/dev/tty` as this is always the terminal (if the program runs on a terminal). This is portable only to Unix-like systems (Linux, BSD, macOS, etc) and won't work on Windows.

```
// +build !windows

tty, err := os.Open("/dev/tty")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("can't open /dev/tty: %s", err)
}
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(tty)
// as you were ...
```

Comment: So in the answer you provided, the program will read only from keyboard, but my intent is to first read from pipe and then switch it to device mode. The goal is to read from stdin which is set to pipe mode in the beginning at the program and starting from this line `reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)`, the mode of stdin is switched to device, i.e. keyboard. Is this even possible? Thanks.

Comment: @jap You read from the tty only when you want to read from the tty and read from stdin when you want to read from stdin. Of course you are allowed to have more than one bufio.Reader at a time; just use another variable!

Answer (score 6):

Probably [scanf](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#hdr-Scanning) could help, check this example:

https://play.golang.org/p/tteQNl0trJp

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Enter your name")

    var name string
    fmt.Scanf("%s", &name)
    fmt.Printf("name = %s\n", name)
}
```

Something a little more elaborated to check if there is something to read from stdin and if not prompt the user:

https://play.golang.org/p/7qeAQ5UNhdQ

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    // check if there is somethinig to read on STDIN
    stat, _ := os.Stdin.Stat()
    if (stat.Mode() & os.ModeCharDevice) == 0 {
        var stdin []byte
        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
        for scanner.Scan() {
            stdin = append(stdin, scanner.Bytes()...)
        }
        if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("stdin = %s\n", stdin)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Enter your name")

        var name string
        fmt.Scanf("%s", &name)
        fmt.Printf("name = %s\n", name)
    }
}
```